# CakePHP unit test code coverage $this->request->data clause not executed

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, xdebug

I am completely new to PHP unit testing (using PHPUnit) and CakePHP(2) as a framework, and I'm coming back to PHP after 5 years away.

I've got a website up and running and am writing unit tests as I go along as best practice.  However, xdebug is showing that one of my clauses is not covered when I believe I am calling it and I just can't see why.  I've googled the hell out of all search terms I can think of and re-read the relevant sections of the cookbook and (while I've learned a lot of other useful things) I didn't find an answer so am hoping that a simple answer is forthcoming from someone in the know :)

Here are the relevant sections of code:

Controller:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

// app/Controller/ClientsController.php
class ClientsController extends AppController {

/* other functions */
 public function edit($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to find client to edit'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
            $client = $this->Client->findById($id);
            if(!$client) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to find client to edit'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }

            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                    $this->Client->id = $id;
                    if ($this->Client->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Client has been updated.'));
                            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                    } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update client'));
                    }
            }

            if (!$this->request->data) {
                    $this->request->data = $client;
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Loading data'));
                }
        }
}
```

Test:

```
<?php

// Test cases for client controller module
class ClientsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array('app.client');

    /* other tests */
        public function testEdit() {

            // Expect success (render)
            $result = $this->testAction('/Clients/edit/1');
            debug($result);
         }
    }
?>
```

The code executes as expected.  If I browse to "/Clients/edit/1", the flash message (Loading data) I expect is displayed indicating that there was no request data, so it's loaded from the `$client`.  The correct data displays in the edit form.

When I call from within my test, I get a success message that the test has passed but xdebug code coverage is showing the `if (!$this->request->data) { .. }` clause is not covered, and no errors are apparent.

This seems counter-intuitive to me, so in a hope to avoid frustration with future (more complex) unit tests - can anyone explain why the test would pass but not execute this clause when it is called during normal access of the page?

(The fixture is correct both in terms of data structure and inserting the data before I'm attempting to edit it.  Calling edit() from a test case with no id or an invalid id correctly executes the relevant clauses, as does passing data that does not pass validation.)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem and I solved by adding the second parameter to testAction():

```
$this->testAction('/Clients/edit/1', array('method' => 'get'));
```

Also you may want to change your

```
if ($this->request->is('post') {
    ...
}
if (!$this->request->data) {
    ...
}
```

To:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.